# How to UPDATE a given mySQL table with random record from another table

Tags: php, mysql, select, random, sql-update

I have a table `tbl_random` like this with about 3000 keywords and model_ids. Keyword are unique, model_ids are not:

```
+---------+------------+---------+---------+--------------+
| keyword | model_id   | make    |  model  |  more_data   |
+---------+------------+---------+---------+--------------+
| apple1  | 15         |         |         |              |
| apple2  | 15         |         |         |              |
| pear    | 205        |         |         |              |
| cherry  | 307        |         |         |              |
| melon   | 5023       |         |         |              |
+---------+------------+---------+---------+--------------+
```

and I have a second table `tbl_products` with about 500K records that contains the actual products and details about them:

```
+---------+--------+------------+
| make    | model  | more_data  |
+---------+--------+------------+
| app1    | 15     | data1      |
| app1    | 15     | data2      |
| cher74  | 307    | data4      |
| melo2   | 5023   | data5      |
| pear53  | 205    | data3      |
+---------+--------+------------+
```

The common identifier between the two tables is `model_id` and `model` respectively.

What I need to do is to write an UPDATE MySQL query, which will update `make` `model` and `more_data`  in `tbl_random` according to those criteria:

The query has to select one random row from `tbl_products` that matches every `model_id` from `tbl_random` for the unique keywords.

I was trying to do this in various ways using UPDATE, LEFT JOIN and SELECT STATEMENTS but cannot get it to work so far.

My latest statement, trying to update only `make` is this one, however it does not work - MySQL starts executing it and nothing happens except that I need to restart MySQL to get it available again:

```
UPDATE tbl_random
        SET tbl_random.make =
        (SELECT tbl_products.make FROM tbl_products                     
        WHERE tbl_random.model_id = tbl_products.model
        GROUP BY tbl_random.keyword       
        ORDER BY RAND())
```

The final desired output for `tbl_random` is this one:

```
+---------+------------+---------+---------+--------------+
| keyword | model_id   | make    |  model  |  more_data   |
+---------+------------+---------+---------+--------------+
| apple1  | 15         | app1    |  15     |  data1       |
| apple2  | 15         | app1    |  15     |  data2       |
| pear    | 205        | pear53  |  205    |  data3       |
| cherry  | 307        | cher74  |  307    |  data4       |
| melon   | 5023       | melo2   |  5023   |  data5       |
+---------+------------+---------+---------+--------------+
```

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: if I only run the select statement from above I get: `#1054 - Unknown column 'tbl_random.model_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: btw, what I did manage to do successfully was to left outer join the two tables with this statement, I only seem unable to update the `tbl_random` table accordingly: `SELECT tbl_random.keyword, tbl_random.model_id, tbl_products.make, tbl_products.model,
      FROM tbl_random LEFT OUTER JOIN
            tbl_products
          ON tbl_random.model_id = tbl_products.model
      GROUP BY tbl_random       
      ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: @Strawberry, the statement in my comment above your's works as it should and delivers the data the way I need it. However, I need to update it in a constant table, not just get it in a select query. If you have other suggestions will be glad to discuss :)

Comment: `And how do you determine that data1 belongs with apple1 and data2 belongs with apple2` - actually I do not need to determine that. app1 and app2 might be related either to apple1 or apple2. The common identified between the two tables is `model_id` and `model`. Since app1 and app2 both have `model=15` they should be randomly placed against any keyword with `model_id=15`

Comment: While an incorrect result is proof of an incorrect solution, a correct result is not proof of a correct solution. Unfortunately, that's where you're at. As for the random distribution of values - this is often symptomatic of poor design. It SHOULD matter!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68494/discussion-between-bradg-and-strawberry).

Comment: I think I've said everything I can on the subject!

Comment: then I guess you cannot really help much.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your inner select returns more than one item and then you are trying to assign it to a single field.

Try adding LIMIT 1 to your inner select.

```
UPDATE tbl_random
    SET tbl_random.make =
    (SELECT tbl_products.make FROM tbl_products                     
    WHERE tbl_random.model_id = tbl_products.model
    GROUP BY tbl_random.keyword       
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
```

I think this might work if the firs option doesn't

```
REPLACE tbl_random (keyword, model_id, make, model) INTO
    SELECT rand2.keyword, rand2.model_id, (SELECT tbl_products.make FROM tbl_products                     
        WHERE rand2.model_id = tbl_products.model
        ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1), rand2.model_id
    FROM tbl_random as rand2
```

Then you will have to run a second query to update the more_data using make and model as the unique key.

Comment: TOP is not a MySQL construct.

Comment: UPDATE tbl_random
SET tbl_random.make =
(SELECT tbl_products.make FROM tbl_products                     
WHERE tbl_random.model_id = tbl_products.model
GROUP BY tbl_random.keyword       
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)

Comment: @BradG I feel like I am misunderstanding the question. I put in a couple more answers please lmk if either one moves you forward. and if not what they do? I think the second one is the closest.

Comment: @BradG did you get a chance to try this?